# input of type file doesn't show data-default-file in mvc view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

using the dropify class, I am trying to show a default image for the box but it show something like that it didn't found the image. this is what I tried until now:

```
<div style="width:35%; float:left; "><input type="file" name="file" class="dropify" data-default-file="~/Content/Dash/assets/images/users/@user.ProfilePic" /></div>

<div style="width:35%; float:left; "><input type="file" name="file" class="dropify" data-default-file="@Path.GetFullPath(user.ProfilePic)" /></div>
```

Knowing that i tried a url from google images and it worked but I need the default image to be the user profile image. if anyone can help I will be glad

Comment: Try: `@Url.Content("~/Content/Dash/assets/images/users/" + user.ProfilePic)`. Although it depended what  user.ProfilePic. Is it the name of the picture?

Comment: Yes it is the name + the extension which is png @TeodorKurtev

Comment: Did the `Url.Content` work?

Comment: Sorry for lateness, I was busy a little bit. and yes it did I just tried it a moment ago.. thanks a lot mate it was a great help from you @TeodorKurtev

Comment: Glad it worked :)